# can I know which versions of Rstudio and r is compatible for package "rmaps"

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package, rmaps

When I tried to use install r package 'Rmaps' I got this warning

> install.packages("rmaps")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Anjana/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘rmaps’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)

My current version of Rstudio is Version 0.99.491 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.

and R version 3.2.3

Comment: Use either the newest version of R 3.3.0, or the maintenance version 3.2.5.

Comment: From where are you trying to download it? CRAN?

Comment: Is this the same package? Capitalization is inconsistent in your question and title. https://github.com/ramnathv/rMaps

Comment: I tried to download it from install packages tab in Rstudio , I tried to manually download it but couldn't find it  . I'll download the latest versions now and check

Comment: Your version of RStudio typically does not matter for package compatibility so focus on your version of R.

Comment: Please _read_ things before just assuming/typing. Ramnath's github repository clearly states it's a github only pkg and provides the _exact R commands_ you need to use to install the package.